# Hive SQL regexp_extract (number)_(number)

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I'm new to hiveSQL and I'm trying to extract a value from the column `col_a` from the data `df` which is in this format:
`\\\"id\\\":\\\"101_12345\\\"`
I only need to extract `101_12345`, but underscore makes it hard to satisfy my need. I tried using `regexp_extract(col_a, '(\\d+)[_](\\d+)')` but only outputs `101`.
Could I get some help with regexp? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried passing `0` as a third argument to `regexp_extract`?

Comment: @isaactfa yes, I just added 0 and it works. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: You don't need the two brackets.

Here's a working solution: `'\\d+[_]\\d+'`

When you put tokens into parentheses, the regex engine will group its match together, **separate from the complete match**. So the final result will comprise the complete match, and two extra matches representing the one before and after the underscore. To avoid this, just remove the brackets as you don't really need them.

In the future, if you want to group a regex together but don't want the result to contain it separately, use a `non-capturing group` given by `(?:)`.

Here's a demo of what your code resulted in, **[hosted at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ardTF1/1)**

Comment: Thank you. If some of the result can contain multiple underscores, then I can just add the non-capturing group to get the full information, correct? In this example, where can I add (?:)?

Comment: If by multiple underscores you mean something like `123_345_678` then it'll be better to tell the regex engine to match (one-or-more digits followed by an optional underscore) repeated multiple times. So basically, `(?:\d+[_]?)+`. Here, I want to group the digit/underscore combo for the regex but I don't want to include it in the result, so non-capturing groups are perfect for this.